# Create a gauge using jsgauge

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsgauge

I have created a gauge using `jsgauge` plugin

What I am not able to do is to control the speed of the needle. It should move to the assigned value a bit slower than the default speed. The needle should also start from 0.

The fiddle for this is http://jsfiddle.net/aryan7987/h45Tr/2/

```
Query(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("#example")
          .gauge({
             min: 0,
             max: 100,
             label: 'EMPLOYEE',
             startangle: 0,
             bands: [{color: "#ff0000", from: 90, to: 100}]
           })
          .gauge('setValue', 59);
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

One of solutions is to use `setInterval` function and increase gauge value step by step with needed delay like this:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            var g = jQuery("#example")
              .gauge({
                 min: 0,
                 max: 100,
                 label: 'RPM',
                 bands: [{color: "#ff0000", from: 90, to: 100}]
               });
              var m = 0;
              var timer = window.setInterval(function()
              {
                m++;
                g.gauge('setValue', m);
                if (m==58)
                {
                    clearInterval(timer);
                }
              }, 200);                   
});
```

The code is quite dirty but you should get a point. Also here working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x6AsB/).

Comment: can i do get two gauges on the same page and rather than giving value directly, can i store the values in a array so that the gauges can take the value form the array.. i am trying it but its not working

Comment: Of course you can. You can create function that will accept gauge object reference, value to set and perform value set for any count of gauges

Comment: thank you but there is another problem, this code is not working in IE. it is just showing a blank screen

Comment: Check this [thread](http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5) this can help. But you should find out what cause problem by yourself or post another question.

Comment: i have seen the thread and i have also searched in the net but none of it is working. can you please tell me why is it not working

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it looks like the speed is hardcoded by defining the delta for each frame.  Here is an monkey patched version to change the speed [see this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h45Tr/3/)

The problem line is:

```
increment = Math.max(Math.abs( that.settings.pointerValue - pointerValue ) / 8, 3);
```

Comment: your fiddle is working but as i am new to this jsgauge, i am not able to understand what you have done in your code, can you please explain it....sorry for the inconvenience..