# creating Gauge using jsGauge

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jsgauge

i am creating a gauge using jsGauge

the answers in this link [Create a gauge using jsgauge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469427/create-a-arraylist-in-net) has helped me but i am trying to make a gauge that can display percentage for example 55.57%.

as shown on jsgauge plugin page http://code.google.com/p/jsgauge/  the fourth gauge shows the value 10.55.  is it possible using jsgauge and the examples shown in the answers  if yes how can it be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the valueFormat option for this. For example:

```
 valueFormat: function (value, decimals) {
                  return value.toFixed(decimals) + '%';
              }
```

---

There is also a `decimals` option that you may need to specify to ensure the proper number of decimal places:

```
options = {
    ...
    decimals: 2,
    ...
 }
```

Does that help?

Comment: it just displays the value like 55% but how can i make the gauge display a value like 55.55% or something like that

Comment: @user1852933 - Please see my edits, you also need to specify a `decimals` option.